# how can i solve this error : NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, sigabrt, xcode-storyboard

I want to push some information to a UITableView so i have to get the location of that View.

and this is the code inside the AppDelegate :

```
player = [[player1Data alloc] init];
player.name = @"Dave Brubeck";
player.game = @"Texas Hold’em Poker";
player.rating = 2;
[playersArray addObject:player];
// to get the player1ViewController
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
player1ViewController *playersViewController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
playersViewController.playersArray = playersArray;
return YES;
```

the error was appearing at :

**player1ViewController *playersViewController = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];**

then the xcode shows that : **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**

the console shows :

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x687a880'**

here is my storyboard layout, i'm not sure if is it the right arrangement.

**Navigation Controller→View Controller(with a button)→Tab Bar Controller→Table View(where i want to show the players info.)**

So sorry my English is not very well, hoping u guys could understand what i'm talkin about.
THX!!

Answer (score 0):

The initialization part of UITabBarController is the problem.Assigning a viewconroller from navigationcontroller stack to UITabBarController??

Prepare an array of VC that you need to show in UITabBarController and load it to the viewcontrollers property of  UITabBarController

Comment: Actually, I don't really understand the meaning of "Assigning a viewconroller from navigationcontroller stack to UITabBarController"
By the way, if I take out the View Controller(with a button), and then change the arrangement of the storyboard like this : 
Tab Bar Controller→Navigation Controller→Table View(where i want to show the players info.)

it works successfully.
So I'm quite confused about How can I implement the process that if I pressed a button, the Tab Bar with a Table View will be push in front of the screen.